# I get from the dataset blue and the last 30 lines red, with using python matplotlib scatter

Tags: matplotlib, scatter-plot

How can I write the code that makes the first 37 lines of the x values I get from the dataset blue and the last 30 lines red, with using python matplotlib scatter

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("bogu.csv",sep = ";")

plt.scatter(df.resim,df.katsayi)
plt.xlabel("resim")
plt.ylabel("katsayi")
#plt.show()
if df.resim[1:37].values:
    plt.scatter(x,color="red")


#%%   sklearn

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
linear_reg=LinearRegression()
x = df.iloc[1:,0].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df.iloc[1:,1].values.reshape(-1,1)
x = x.astype(np.float)
y = y.astype(np.float)
linear_reg.fit(x,y)
#array=np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]).reshape(-1,1) # deneyim
#plt.scatter(x,y)
y_head=linear_reg.predict(x)
plt.plot(x,y_head,color="red",label="linear")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replicate your dataset, I created a file called bogu.csv with the numbers `x` as 0 to 66 in the "resim" column  and the second column, "katsayi" was `x**2`.

To colour in `plt.scatter`, you can simply pass a list to the `c` keyword. Use a list comprehension to iterate over the index of `df`, and make the colour `"b"` for blue, and `"r"` for red.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv("bogu.csv", sep=";")
c = ["b" if x < 37 else "r" for x in df.index]
plt.scatter(df.resim, df.katsayi, c=c)
plt.xlabel("resim")
plt.ylabel("katsayi")
plt.show()
```

[Here is what the final plot produces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6mu5j.png)

Hope that helps!